# How to deploy entity framework code first for a standalone app

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, deployment, connection-string, database-first

I have just finished an standalone desktop application in C# and .Net. For the app, I need to access several existing SQL Server tables for various data. I accomplished it with Entity Framework 6 code first. My question is how I should update the connection string in app.config during a customer installation to reflect customer's SQL Server configurations. What steps are generally involved? What options are available to me? I'll use Inno Setup for the app installation.

Thank you.

Comment: need help on same topic. It would be great to share, if you found something.

Comment: I'm surprised no one has answered my question. Because of time constraint I gave up EF approach and went with ODBC. But I did find a nice article on this subject: http://www.ttkalec.com/blog/deploying-net-apps-that-use-ef-and-sql-ce-4-0/. I hope it would be useful for you or someone else.